# T-Sql Declare and set

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is my statement

Why I get those errors Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select', Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'. ???

```
BEGIN
Declare @idToutesPlantesDérivés  int 
DECLARE @idPlantesDérivés  int 

SET @idPlantesDérivés = select(ID_CHIMQ FROM dbo.SOUS_CATGR where Name = 'plantes et ses dérivés')

SET @idToutesPlantesDérivés = select(ID_CHIMQ  FROM dbo.SOUS_CATGR where Name = 'toutes les autres plantes et dérivés')

   select @idToutesPlantesDérivés
END
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One way

```
BEGIN
Declare @idToutesPlantesDérivés  int 
DECLARE @idPlantesDérivés  int 

SET @idPlantesDérivés = ( SELECT ID_CHIMQ 
FROM dbo.SOUS_CATGR
where Name = 'plantes et ses dérivés')

SET @idToutesPlantesDérivés = ( SELECT ID_CHIMQ 
  FROM dbo.SOUS_CATGR
where Name = 'toutes les autres plantes et dérivés')

   select @idToutesPlantesDérivés
END
```

or

```
BEGIN
Declare @idToutesPlantesDérivés  int 
DECLARE @idPlantesDérivés  int 

SELECT @idPlantesDérivés = ID_CHIMQ  
FROM dbo.SOUS_CATGR
where Name = 'plantes et ses dérivés'

SELECT @idToutesPlantesDérivés = ID_CHIMQ 
FROM dbo.SOUS_CATGR
where Name = 'toutes les autres plantes et dérivés'

   select @idToutesPlantesDérivés
END
```

Answer (score 3):

Another syntax for setting a value for a variable with SELECT looks like:

```
SELECT @variable = column_name FROM some_table WHERE ...
```

So for your case:

```
BEGIN
Declare @idToutesPlantesDérivés  int 
DECLARE @idPlantesDérivés  int 

select @idPlantesDérivés = ID_CHIMQ FROM dbo.SOUS_CATGR where Name = 'plantes et ses dérivés'

select @idToutesPlantesDérivés = ID_CHIMQ  FROM dbo.SOUS_CATGR where Name = 'toutes les autres plantes et dérivés'

   select @idToutesPlantesDérivés
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
(select ID_SOUS_CATGR_AGENT_CHIMQ FROM dbo.MAD_SOUS_CATGR_AGENT_CHIMQ where NM_SOUS_CATGR_AGENT_CHIMQ = 'plantes et ses dérivés')
```

Answer (score 0):

move your parentheses:

```
BEGIN
Declare @idToutesPlantesDérivés  int 
DECLARE @idPlantesDérivés  int 

SET @idPlantesDérivés = (select (ID_CHIMQ 
                        FROM dbo.SOUS_CATGR
                        where Name = 'plantes et ses dérivés')

SET @idToutesPlantesDérivés = (select (ID_CHIMQ 
                            FROM dbo.SOUS_CATGR
                            where Name = 'toutes les autres plantes et dérivés')

   select @idToutesPlantesDérivés
END
```